# PHP Update MySQL value and redirect to a page

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im still new in PHP, I'd like help in a php example where I click a link, a value gets updated in mysql and redirect the user to a page.

Your will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read this article befor you ask a question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please don't ask a question like this. It's very easy to ask someone help!

Comment: @Rokas Mikalkėnas gave good solution.many possible ways are there Google it for more solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "UPDATE MyGuests SET lastname='Doe' WHERE id=2";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    // if all ok, redirecting
    header("Location: http://example.com/myOtherPage.php");
    die();
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```